# Two-Way communication between classes python (edited + code added)

Tags: python, oop, logic

So, I have classes that need to communicate with each other. For example, I build client of chat program. One class handle the sockets, and another class that handle the GUI. So the GUI class has to get the received data from the sockets class, and in addition has to send the messages through the socket class.

The problem is that if you make one class contain the other you cant communicate two-way. You need to pass an instance of the parent into the child But I don't think that passing the instance is the right way.

Whats the best what to do that?

Here some code for example, hope its clear (please read the comments in the code to understand better):

```
class MainWindow:
    def __init__(self, master, username, sock):
        # Tkinter Code Here

    def insert_msg(self, data):  # d_type 1 - msg
        self.chat_textbox.insert(END, "\n%s %s" % (datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M:%S'), data))
        self.chat_textbox.see(END)

    def send_msg(self, data, d_type=SEND_ENUM.TYPE_MSG, arg=0):
        data = str(data)
        if len(data) >= 1 and d_type == SEND_ENUM.TYPE_MSG:
            try:
                self.chat_textbox.insert(END, "\n%s [Me] %s" % (datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M:%S'), data))

                # For example, here has to use send_msg method from SockHandler class
                # self.sock_handler.send_msg(data)

            except sock_handling.ConnectionError as error:
                self.chat_textbox.insert(END, "\nError: The message was not delivered", "RED")
            else:
                pass
            finally:
                self.msg_box_entry.delete(0, 'end')
                self.chat_textbox.see(END)
        elif d_type != SEND_ENUM.TYPE_MSG:
            try:
                # also here self.sock_handler.send_msg(data, d_type)
            except sock_handling.ConnectionError as error:
                pass
        else:
            pass

class SockHandler:
    def __init__(self, client_socket):
        # nothing relevant for the Q

    def send_msg(self, data, d_type=SEND_ENUM.TYPE_MSG, arg=0):
        packed_data = self.pack_data(d_type, arg, data)

        if len(data) >= 1 and d_type == SEND_ENUM.TYPE_MSG:
            try:
                self.client_socket.send(packed_data)
            except socket.error:
                raise ConnectionError("Connection Error")

            finally:
                pass

        elif d_type != SEND_ENUM.TYPE_MSG:
            try:
                self.client_socket.send(packed_data)
            except socket.error:
                raise ConnectionError("Connection Error")

    def receive_data(self):
        try:
            while True:
                recv_data = self.client_socket.recv(self.BUFFER)
                (d_type,), data = struct.unpack("!I", recv_data[:4]), recv_data[4:]
                if d_type == RECV_ENUM.TYPE_MSG:

                    # For example, here has to use insert_msg method from MainWindow class

                elif d_type == RECV_ENUM.TYPE_USER_LIST:
                    pass
                elif d_type == RECV_ENUM.TYPE_POKE:
                    pass
        except socket.error:
            self.client_socket.close()
            raise ConnectionError("Connection Error")
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not instantiate the `SockHandler` as an attribute to the `MainWindow`?

Like this:

```
class MainWindow:
    def __init__(self, master, username, sock):
        # Tkinter Code Here
        self.socket_handler = SockHandler(sock)
```

Now you can send messages from `MainWindow` using `self.socket_handler.send_msg`

For receiving, have your socket store received data where that the `MainWindow` can retrieve it.

Like this:

```
class SockHandler:
    def __init__(self, client_socket):
        # nothing relevant for the Q
        self.received_messages = Queue.Queue()
```

Now you need to expose a way for `MainWindow` to access the received messages. If you want, you can have it directly fetch the messages by querying the queue but I would prefer something like this:

```
# Within the SockHandler Class
def get_next_message():
    try:
        return self.received_messages.get(True, 5)
    except:
        return None
```

It doesn't matter if `SockHandler` or `MainWindow` handles the Timeout exception in this method. That is up to you.